# How do I stop my widgets from opening in a new window when I call them in customtkinter?

Tags: python, oop, tkinter, inheritance, customtkinter

The following code is a section from a wider program creating a GUI for a school project, and I don't know why the class PreferencesGUI() isn't positioning itself within the window I created in the baseSetup class?

```
class baseSetup(customtkinter.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()


        #MAIN SETUP
        self.title("Recs")
        self.geometry("898x506")
        
        self.grid_columnconfigure((1),weight=0)
        self.grid_columnconfigure((2,3,4,5),weight=0)
        self.grid_rowconfigure((0,1,2,3,4),weight=0)
        self.grid_rowconfigure((15),weight=1)

        #create menu panel on left of screen
        self.frameLeft = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self, width=140, corner_radius=0)
        self.frameLeft.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=16, sticky="nsew")
        self.frameLeft.grid_rowconfigure(4, weight=1)
        self.frameLeftMenuTitle = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.frameLeft, text="TITLE", font=("Arial", 40))
        self.frameLeftMenuTitle.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=(20, 10))

        self.frameLeftHomeButton = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.frameLeft,text="Home", font=("Arial",16), command=buttonPressHome)
        self.frameLeftHomeButton.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=30, pady=(20, 10))

        self.frameLeftPreferencesButton = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.frameLeft,text="Preferences", font=("Arial",16), command=buttonPressPreferences)
        self.frameLeftPreferencesButton.grid(row=2,column=0,padx=30, pady=(20, 10))

        self.frameLeftInfoButton = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.frameLeft,text="Info", font=("Arial",16), command=buttonPressInfo)
        self.frameLeftInfoButton.grid(row=3,column=0,padx=30, pady=(20, 10))

        self.frameLeftAccountButton = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.frameLeft,text="Account", font=("Arial",16), command=buttonPressAccount)
        self.frameLeftAccountButton.grid(row=4,column=0,padx=30, pady=(20, 10),sticky="new")


        self.mainloop()


class PreferencesGUI(customtkinter.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()   

        #create central part of preferences gui, with sliders, tickboxes, gui mode, account management, etc.
        frameMiddleWidth = 100
        min = 0
        max = 100
        startVal = int(max/2)
        sliderLabelPadyTop=21
        sliderLabelPadyBot=0
        sliderBoxPadyTop=0
        sliderBoxPadyBot=36

        self.frameMaster = customtkinter.CTkScrollableFrame(self,width=675, corner_radius=0,fg_color="transparent")
        self.frameMaster.grid(column=1,row=0,rowspan=16,columnspan=5,sticky="nsew",)

        #top frame with title in
        self.frameMiddle = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self.frameMaster,corner_radius=10)
        self.frameMiddle.grid(row=0, column=1, rowspan=1, columnspan=5, padx=(10,10), pady=(10,10), sticky="nsew")
        self.frameMiddle.grid_rowconfigure(1,weight=1)
        self.frameMiddleTitle = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.frameMiddle, text="Preferences",font=("Arial", 40))
        self.frameMiddleTitle.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=150, pady=(10, 10), columnspan=5)
```

[This is what it looks like when I run the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcouB.png)

[This is what I want it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlHYY.png)

I originally had it as just 1 class, but as I add functionality etc it's going to get really annoying to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `PreferencesGUI` is inheriting from `customtkinter.CTk` just like your main `baseSetup` window, so when you call `super().__init__()` on `PreferencesGUI`, it creates another instance of `CTk`.

If you want `PreferencesGUI` to act as a child of `baseSetup`, you probably want to inherit from something like `Frame` instead of `CTk`. That way, you can instantiate `PreferencesGUI` from within `baseSetup`. You haven't shown where `PreferencesGUI` is being instantiated, but it will likely need to be moved into your main class.

```
import tkinter as tk  # import tkinter to give us access to the tk.Frame widget class

class baseSetup(customtkinter.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # instantiate PreferencesGUI passing 'self' (this class) as the master
        self.prefs_gui = PreferencesGUI(self)
        # add prefs_gui to the UI
        self.prefs_gui.pack()
        ...  # code omitted for brevity
        self.mainloop()


class PreferencesGUI(tk.Frame):  # inherit from Frame here instead, for example
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)  # pass the same 'master' to the Frame superclass
        ...  # code omitted for brevity
```

FWIW, you don't *have* to inherit from `tk.Frame`, but it's probably the easiest thing to deal with in terms of a "generic" container widget